# Leading spaces appear in textarea when populating from Jsonreult

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP MVC3 application I have the following contoller action:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonStatus(string id)
{
    var statuses = repo.GetEventLogMessages(new Guid(id));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string status in statuses)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(status);
    }

    StatusMessage sm = new StatusMessage { Status = sb.ToString(), Processing = importing };

    return Json(sm,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the Json that is returned, Status can be multiple lines of text that gets put into a Textarea.  Here is the relavant portion of the view with the JQuery:

```
    @model RAM.Models.StatusMessage
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id="status" cols="30" rows="7" wrap="off" class="statusText" >@Model.Status</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function getStatus(processID) {
        var url = '@(Url.Action("GetJsonImportStatus"))' + '/' + processID;
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            $('#status').text(data.Status);
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the text that ends up in the text area will have a leading space on each line except the first so it will look somthing like this:

> This is line1
>    This is line2
>    This is line3

The value of Status in the Json looks like this:
"This is line1\r\nThis is line2\r\nThis is line3\r\n"

**How do I remove or prevent the leading spaces?**

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/nkBJV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used /r and it looks fine in IE/FF

Comment: Changed sb.AppendLine(status) to sb.Append(status); sb.Append("\r"); and I got what I wanted - thanks